# 2d array, trim with specified value

Tags: arrays, algorithm

What's a good way to trim a 2d array with a specified value?

```
A = [0 0 0 0 0]
    [1 2 3 0 0]
    [4 0 6 0 0]
    [0 0 0 0 0]

B = trim(A, 0)
// results in:
// B = [1 2 3]
//     [4 0 6]
```

The trim operation should be able to cut away from any of the four sides.

Comment: Great question. Not so great effort. :/

Comment: If `A = [1 1 1; 0 0 0; 3 3 3]`, would `trim(A, 0)` remove the middle row? Or does your `trim` function only trim inwards starting from the perimeter?

Comment: I'm trying it right now. The method I'm using is to go check entire rows and columns for the value. row=0 to N, row=N to 0, col=0 to M, col=M to 0, to get the starting and ending rows and columns, but that just seems ridiculous. I'm asking for any way to possibly get something better.

Comment: Trimming has to start from the outside. I'm not even sure how to get one resulting B = trim(A, 0) from that one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pseudocode:

```
trim(array[WIDTH][HEIGHT], trimmed):

    // top left corner will be (xmin, ymin)
    xmin = WIDTH
    ymin = HEIGHT

    // bottom right corner will be (xmax, ymax)
    xmax = -1
    ymax = -1

    for (y = 0; y < HEIGHT; y++):
        for (x = 0; x < WIDTH; x++):
            if (array[x][y] != trimmed):
                if (xmin > x) xmin = x
                if (xmax < x) xmax = x
                if (ymin > y) ymin = y
                if (ymax < y) ymax = y

    if (xmin == WIDTH)
        return an empty array
    else
        return sub-array with top left corner in (xmin, ymin) 
               and bottom right corner in (xmax, ymax)
```

Time complexity is `O(WIDTH * HEIGHT)`, space complexity is `O(1)`.

In some programming languages (like C or C++) that `for` loop should be much faster due to [locality of reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locality_of_reference) and [vectorization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_vectorization).